# How do I get React to work with Babel and Gulp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I keep getting error after compilation: `can't find variable: exports`.

Here are my files.

Gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('react', function() {
    gulp.src('./resources/components/*.jsx')
        .pipe(babel({presets: ['react', 'es2015']}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['react']);
```

./resources/components/HelloWorld.jsx

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react'

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Hello World</td>
                    <td>Loren ipsum</td>
                    <td>Delete | Update</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        );
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld/>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Crossover - Project</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

    <main id="main"></main>
    <script src="./js/HelloWorld.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Here is the output.

HelloWorld.js

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var HelloWorld = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(HelloWorld, _Component);

  function HelloWorld(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, HelloWorld);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(HelloWorld).call(this, props));
  }

  _createClass(HelloWorld, [{
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      return _react2.default.createElement(
        'table',
        null,
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'tr',
          null,
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'th',
            null,
            'Title'
          ),
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'th',
            null,
            'Description'
          ),
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'th',
            null,
            'Actions'
          )
        ),
        _react2.default.createElement(
          'tr',
          null,
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'td',
            null,
            'Hello World'
          ),
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'td',
            null,
            'Loren ipsum'
          ),
          _react2.default.createElement(
            'td',
            null,
            'Delete | Update'
          )
        )
      );
    }
  }]);

  return HelloWorld;
}(_react.Component);

// this is where the error occurs
exports.default = HelloWorld;


ReactDOM.render(_react2.default.createElement(HelloWorld, null), document.getElementById('main'));
```

I am very new to react and I don't want to use webpack because I already have a webserver + framework running and I want to integrate react into my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including `HelloWorld.js` as is in the HTML:

```
<script src="./js/HelloWorld.js"></script>
```

But the browser has no knowledge of `exports` and common-js module features, and therefore does not create an exports variable. This code is executed in the browser, not in node.js environment.

**EDIT:**

So, I don't know if this is the right place, but I am going to try to make some points so you can be up to speed as soon as possible.

1) ES6 is a spec, and the major browser vendors have implemented some of it, but not all. So if you are going to write your code using ES6 (AKA ES2015), as anyone should, nowadays, you should use a transpiler to be sure your code will be parsed and executed correctly in every browser. The best transpiler is Babel, as you seem to know. Plus Babel can transpile JSX code, which you should use if you use React (note that JSX has nothing to do with ES6);

2) Since you use a transpiler, you **have** to transpile your ES6 code on every change you make to see the result;

3) Gulp is a node module, and a wonderful tool to automate your build system: watch your code for change, transpile your code on every change, run a local server (as you seem to know), and so many other things;

4) You can use webpack in conjunction with gulp. Even though I recommend just using npm scripts and webpack, you could do this smoothly : integrate webpack into your existing build system for now, and try in the future to replace progressively your gulp tasks with webpack and npm scripts, as you get to know webpack better.

Summary:

*"[Node,] ES6, Babel, Gulp, and React can work together"* this way:

- Install and use node to be able to install and use gulp
- Install and use gulp to watch your file for change
- Install react, react-dom, babel and its module ES2015 and JSX, and write your react code with ES6 features and JSX
- Use gulp to transpile your ES6/JSX code and concatenate it in a single file, and to run your webserver (and optionally browser-sync ;-) )

I hope I made things clearer in your mind.

Maybe you could look at this github project and look at the branches: https://github.com/laruiss/front-boilerplate

Comment: My understanding is that node environment needs to create a single JS file in ES5 that the browser can parse. How do I create that file? I want to do it using Gulp and maybe Node but not use something like Webpack. I want the react files to be static instead of node generating it every time. I really do not understand how ES6, Babel, Gulp, and React can work together.

Comment: I just did and thank you! After a lot of researching I actually understood React and your edit made me clarify a lot of things. One thing I noticed was that React does not work well with gulp. So, first I tried to use browserify but it was slow. Now, I went back to using Webpack because it really is great for dev environment.